# TSQL: Ranking records by using different columns

Tags: t-sql, join

I have a table with persons and their expenses and some other columns. What I need is to create two new columns: ranking1 and ranking2. These rankings are "calculated" by using some columns and by using aggregates.

```
ranking1: if total of person expenses exceeds 1000 then ranking 1 else ranking 0
ranking2: (if Col1 = 1 then 0 else 5) + (if Col2 = 1 then 0 else 7) + (if Col3 = 1 then 5 else 10)
```

What I need is to have the original table (unaltered) with these two new columns that give me the ranking for each person.

My query:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3
       ((CASE Col1 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 5 END) + 
        (CASE WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 7 END) + 
        (CASE WHEN Col3 = 1 THEN 5 WHEN Col3 = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 10 END)) as ranking, tmp.Expenses    from table t
left join (select id, Person, 
          (case when temp.expenses > 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as UserExpenses 
           from (select id, Person, sum(Expenses) as expenses 
           from table 
           group by id, Person) temp) tmp
on t.Person = tmp.Person and t.id = tmp.id
order by ranking desc, tmp.UserExpenses desc
```

I am dubious about if this query will give me what I want, that is the original unaltered table with two new columns as ranking. Especially I am dubious about left join, is it the right join? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your query should bring you right results. Below is a little bit simplified version of your query:

```
select  Col1,
        Col2, 
        Col3
        (CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 5 END) + 
        (CASE WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 7 END) + 
        (CASE WHEN Col3 = 1 THEN 5 WHEN Col3 = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 10 END) as ranking, 
        (case when temp.expenses > 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as Expenses    
from [table] t
OUTER APPLY (select id, 
                    Person, 
                    sum(Expenses) as expenses 
            from [table] 
            where t.Person = Person and t.id = id
            group by id, Person
            ) temp
order by ranking desc, temp.expenses desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions!

Comment: My pleasure! Great if it helps!